# Trying To Animate an Image's Alpha

Tags: android

I'm building the design of an app I'm developing, and I'm trying to get an image to fade into the screen.  However, the image remains invisible while it translates successfully.  This is the code:

```
facebookLoginButton = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.facebookLoginButton); // Start of facebookLoginButton code
facebookLoginButton.setTranslationY(250f);
facebookLoginButton.setImageAlpha(0);
facebookLoginButton.animate().translationYBy(-250f).alpha(1).setDuration(1500); // End of facebookLoginButton code
```

I know that the image moves successfully because when I remove the `facebookLoginButton.setImageAlpha(0);`, I see the image moving into the screen.  How come the image stays invisible?

Note: There's no functionality to the app yet, which is why my button is an ImageView.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`ViewPropertyAnimator`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewPropertyAnimator.html) returned by `View.animate()` follows the builder pattern. Each of the methods return the pending `ViewPropertyAnimator`, you must call [`start()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewPropertyAnimator.html#start()) to activate the animation.

**Edit:** The alpha is also not animating because [`setImageAlpha()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html#setImageAlpha(int)) sets the alpha value for the image within the `View`, not the `View` itself. While `ViewPropertyAnimator` animates the alpha of the `View`, not the image within the `View`. Although [`ImageView.setAlpha(int alpha)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html#setAlpha(int)) is deprecated, [`View.setAlpha(float alpha)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setAlpha(float)) is not, and you must use this method to set the alpha for the `View`. Then `ViewPropertyAnimator` can animate that value:

```
facebookLoginButton.setTranslation(250F);
facebookLoginButton.setAlpha(0.0F);
facebookLoginButton.animate()
            .translationYBy(-250F)
            .alpha(1.0F)
            .setDuration(1500)
            .start();
```

Comment: Thank you for teaching me something new.  However, the image still remains invisible.

Comment: Wow, thanks for this new information!  Now I don't have to set the initial Alpha to 0 under the image's properties.  Thank you very much!